# Documentation for DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR=MYS in DB2

Tags: mysql, vector, db2, compatibility

I saw in many articles and blogs the new features in DB2 express-c 9.7.4. I am specially interested in the compatibility vector with MySQL, in order to use Limit and Offset in the queries, however I cannot find any documentation related to this new feature in the Information Center.

The only "official" documentation is at http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-1006db2expressc972/index.html which is an article written by the Campus Program Manager.

This feature is not mentionned in the information Center for DB2 9.7, in the section fixpack 4 features: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.wn.doc/doc/c0056050.html

I would like to know if this feature is completely supported in all DB2 versions?
If this feature is only available for db2 express-C, where is its documentation? is the only documentation the Raul Chong's article in DeveloperWorks?
Is it safe to use this feature, or is it just a test and its future is unknown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm on the DB2 Express-C team at IBM. The MYS feature is official and safe to use. There's a documentation defect open against the Info Center article to address the issue you mention.

This also needs to be documented better, but MYS is synonymous with:

```
db2set DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR=4000
```

All the numeric vector values can be combined any way you like via hex addition. There's an article by Serge Rielau on developeWorks that explains how this works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR` has been available since [DB2 9.7 Workgroup and Enterprise](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.porting.doc/doc/r0052867.html) editions.

According to Raul it's new to Express-C in 9.7.4, particularly the "MYS" setting. I'd take that as being "official." A DB2 Express-C book is available [here](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/dw/db2/express-c/wiki/Getting_Started_with_DB2_Express_v9.7_p4.pdf), otherwise documentation is limited as it's their free product.

Comment: Yes, I know that the compatibility vector has been release time ago, specially for Oracle compatibility, and the InfoCenter talks about that. I do not have any doubt about that. In the other side, the info center does not talk about the vector compatibility for MySQL, and this is the purpose of my question, because it was announced, but only in that article.